# google-cloud-php Document AI: INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to use [google-cloud-php](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php) to send documents to Google Document AI for processing.

Here is an example of my code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[###].json');

use Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\Document;
use Google\Cloud\DocumentAI\V1\DocumentProcessorServiceClient;

$document              = array();
$document['mime_type'] = 'application/pdf';
$document['content']   = file_get_contents('file.pdf');

$inlineDocument = new Document($document);

$postBody                    = array();
$postBody['inlineDocument']  = $inlineDocument;
$postBody['skipHumanReview'] = true;

$documentProcessorServiceClient = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient();

$formattedName     = $documentProcessorServiceClient->processorName('[###]', 'eu', '[###]');
$operationResponse = $documentProcessorServiceClient->processDocument($formattedName, $postBody);
```

I am passing my arguments according to following documents:

[processDocument Documentation](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-document-ai/v0.1.1/documentai/v1/documentprocessorserviceclient?method=processDocument)

[Document Documentation](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-document-ai/v0.1.1/documentai/v1/document?method=__construct)

However, I get the following response:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: { "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", "code": 3, "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [] } thrown in \vendor\google\gax\src\ApiException.php on line 139
```

For some reason, the following document mentions to pass one argument as "mimeType" instead of "mime_type" compared to the previous link:

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request

I tried that as well but that throws an exception in the php class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The same [question](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/4713) was asked on Github . Posting here for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue, the problem is when other region than 'us'.  If so, you should specify the apiEndpoint:

```
$documentProcessorServiceClient = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient([
    'apiEndpoint' => 'eu-documentai.googleapis.com'
]);
```